# How to just return a defined variable from an observable synchronously

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic2

So I inherited and angular/ionic app that I am trying to do some testing on, the app is having a bunch of issues, I am currently in the process of changing the functions that store/return the data it uses. The app is set up to consume this data through observables which I am not familiar with at all. All the functions in the app are doing a `.subscribe()` where the original functions are performing some async function. I want to modify these functions to just return a global variable synchronously, I tried this but this does not seem to be working. Can anyone help me out here?

```js
public getDataObject(): Observable<DataObject> {
  return Observable.create((do: Data Object) => {
    if (this.globalDataObject === null) {
      throw new Error("Test Error, global var is null")
    }
    let alert = this.alrtCntrl.create({
      title: "INFO",
      subTitle: `Returning Global Data Object Variable`,
      buttons: ["OK"],
    })
    alert.present();
    return this.globalDataObject;
  })
}
```

Comment: You can just return the DataObject.... that'll be sent to the subscriber.  Handle everything else once it's returned.  To catch errors, use .pipe, tap, catchError... If you are just returning an object you don't need to use Observables.... ex: getDataObject(): DataObject {...}  https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

Comment: It's nice to have them them for services as it's a more powerful form of a "promise".  (I would leave them in place and deal with them in a simple way...)  You should probably include the method that subscribes to the observable.

Comment: yeah this was mainly just for testing, so this function is being called in basically every single component in the app and I did not want to have to modify how it was handling the returned value throughout the app, just for the sake of saving time. This would not be a long term solution. I was just curious if there was a quick way to keep the return value as an observable but just return a defined variable synchronously if that makes sense. I have only seen Observables being used for async operations which makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the `Observable.create` wrapper with the `of()` operator should give you the behavior you're looking for.

```
public getDataObject(): Observable<DataObject> {
  if (this.globalDataObject === null) {
    throw new Error("Test Error, global var is null")
  }
  const alert = this.alrtCntrl.create({
    title: "INFO",
    subTitle: `Returning Global Data Object Variable`,
    buttons: ["OK"],
  })
  alert.present();
  return of(this.globalDataObject);
}
```

The `of()` operator will emit whatever synchronous value you put inside.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was trying to avoid lol. It's expecting an observable back from this function basically in every component in the app. I was able to get it to work by doing observable.fromPromise and then just resolving it with the value of the global variable right away.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. The `of()` operator is a quick way to turn a synchronous value into an observable.

Comment: oh awesome! thank man I appreciate it.